# Где лучше хранить двоичные данные: в БД или отдельном файле? [ASP.NET MVC 3]

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток.

Есть база данных в которой хранятся учётные записи пользователей. К каждому пользователю привязаны два двоичных файла. Первый файл занимает около 30КБ, второй занимает около 300КБ. Со временем количество пользователей может исчисляться сотнями тысяч.

Первый вариант - хранить эти данные в базе данных. Поле Data в таблице будет иметь тип varbinary(MAX):

```
public ActionResult GetWorld()
{
    var world = db.GetWorld(...);

    return File(world.Data, "application/octet-stream");
}

public ActionResult SaveWorld(HttpPostedFileBase worldData)
{
    var world = db.GetWorld(...);

    world.Data = new byte[worldData.ContentLength];
    worldData.InputStream.Read(world.Data, 0, worldData.ContentLength);
}
```

Второй вариант - хранить эти данные в виде отдельных файлов:

```
public ActionResult GetWorld()
{
    var world = db.GetWorld(...);

    string pathToWorldData = Server.MapPath(
        string.Format("~/App_Data/Worlds/{0}.dat", world.Id));

    return File(pathToWorldData, "application/octet-stream");
}

public ActionResult SaveWorld(HttpPostedFileBase worldData)
{
    var world = db.GetWorld(...);

    string pathToWorldData = Server.MapPath(
        string.Format("~/App_Data/Worlds/{0}.dat", world.Id));

    worldData.SaveAs(pathToWorldData);
}
```

Есть ещё другой вариант - varbinary(MAX) и FILESTREAM, но чем он по сути отличается от второго? Только будет много возни в коде.

Answer (score 2):

Если хранить данные как поле таблицы, база будет пухнуть. Использование опции FILESTREAM позволяет хранить данные как отдельные файлы, но при этом с поддержкой транзакционности. Правда, лог базы данных всё равно будет пухнуть, его надо будет чистить периодически.

Теперь о проблемах. FILESTREAM работает только с Windows-аутентификацией при обращении к БД. Возможно, я чего-то не нашёл, но по-другому у меня не получилось. В сочетании с тем, что диспетчер служб Windows любит терять пароли после пары перезагрузок, работать с этой опцией становится совсем весело. Ещё у меня была такая фигня, что после установки какого-то из обновлений Windows её было не включить.

С учётом того, что Microsoft любят добавлять всё время новые возможности своих продуктов, не доводя до ума старые, используйте лучше файлы. Если так надо сделать поддержку транзакционности, посмотрите в сторону распределённых транзакций.

Answer (score 1):

Бинарные данные лучше хранить в файлах. Картинки, видео и музыку никто не хранит в БД. Не стоит лишний раз все усложнять. Для хранения большого количества файлов обычно создают множество подпапок, например можно хранить файлы для первой тысячи записей в папке /0/, для второй в /1/ и т. д.

Comment: Хранят, еще как, только в специально обученных/подготовленных этому БД. Basho, вон, Riak CS продает, например.

Но не в SQL Server. На MS Research по этому поводу есть [статья](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525) (правда, старая, от 2006).

Answer (score 0):

ну если есть деньги, то в БД, т.к. 500 мегабайт стандартно вроде, дальше уже доп $$$

а также из базы дольше дергаться будет, факт

поле надо выбирать не varchar точно, раз ты байты будешь там хранить, лучше уж varbinary
(кстати, для xml файлов есть тип xml в 2008)

я бы посоветовал только путь к файлам хранить в БД, а файл дергать из файловой системы

Comment: Хранить путь не обязательно. Оптимальнее в конфигурации приложения указать корневой каталог для файлов, а относительный путь уже строить в коде, основываясь на ID и т.д.
В итоге - минус одна колонка данных, плюс возможность настройки.