# Подскажите как загрузить картинку и сохранить ее в базу

Tags: c#

Всем здравствуйте,сделал парсер, все работает вменяемо, сохраняю результат парсинга в базу(MSSQL) и потом из базы отображаю его в GridView. Вытягиваю из нужного мне раздела картинку, это фотография, сейчас в базе данных храниться просто урл фотографии, хочется фото отображать, вопрос, как лучше хранить фотографию в самой базе,или при надобности подгружать ее из интернета сразу в GridView. Хранить на диске как то не хочется, много будет их. Возникает вопрос в эффективности этого. Как закачивать и сохранить в базу правильно. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Связанные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/72679/Как-загрузить-картинку-в-базу-данных-и-отобразить-фото-в-объекте-picture/419496#419496 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/160859/Где-лучше-хранить-двоичные-данные-в-БД-или-отдельном-файле-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Храните ваше изображение в базе как массив байтов / byte[] . Используйте MemoryStream для перевода в/из byte[].

Comment: Правильно будет хранить локальный урл

Comment: @JavaJunior Да тогда на компе будет храниться тысяЧИ картинок

Comment: Ну и что, иначе будет хранится тысячи*тысячи ненужных байт в БД

Comment: Тогда проще отображать, что называется на лету асинхронно.

Comment: что вам мешает асинхронно читать с диска? То же чтение, что и из БД, только БД будет гораздо меньше без картинок

Comment: Сейчас я вас всех примирю. В SqlServer можно использовать [FILESTREAM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: _Развечтение с БД не будет быстрее чтения с диска?_

Comment: @Jagailo, ну сама база так же храниться на диске => будут все те же IO операции. Единственный, возможно, +- это то, что база может кешировать результаты запроса, но вроде и файловый сервер умеет это делать.

Comment: @iluxa1810, да но БД работает в обход ОС, в отличии от файлов. Конечно, лучше хранить картинки на диске, но БД быстрее будет.